# proving Hilbert's Hotel theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I am taking undergraduate set theory course and given this problem but cannot think of any solution. Should I use this Hilbert's hotel theorem to prove other Hilbert's hotel theorems (1), (2) in the problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon how the book is organized. Does Hilbert's hotel theorem appear before that exercise? Then, yes, you can use it (hint: use induction).